# CSS: Content floats out of box in Chrome and IE, just Firefox works

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Good morning,

I have some trouble with a CSS-styled formular in a div-box.

The page is built up like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="loginbox">
            <form>
            <!-- formular stuff, designed as table -->
            </form>
        </div> <!-- loginbox -->
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

(just for basic understanding, complete fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hLf4v2tp/)

The div "loginbox" ist styled like this:

```
#loginbox
{

    border: 1px solid #333333;
    width: 340px;
    height: 190px;
    font-size: small;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

When accessed on firefox, the whole formular is displayed inside the box, but when accessed on Chrome or Internet Explorer, it is displayed below the box.

I have to admit that I have very little knowledge of CSS, I just need it for this little box. Has somebody an idea what going wrong with the stylesheet? Do I need any browser hacks just for Chrome and IE?

Thank you!

Comment: why is your #loginbox position:absolute? you should also show us the rest of `<form>` code and css!? (maybe create a fiddle for us!) probably you have also used position stylings there which are not as you want them (http://jsfiddle.net/9zt0aveb/) this is your code which will work in every browser!?

Comment: @caramba #loginbox is absolute to center it in the screen center. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLf4v2tp/

Comment: your code is working fine on chrome, safari and firefox on OSX. form is always inside the box!

Comment: meh, I'm working on windows, are there any OS-specific things in CSS (or in this particular case) I have to take care about?

Comment: from what I know not for so "big things". use the browser debugger/inspector tools and check which css rule is braking your layout (IE press F12, Chrome right click "Inspect Element" (bzw. "Element untersuchen";) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements